# Combining output to CSV from two Powershell commands

Tags: powershell

I am trying to take an existing CSV file and append it with the output from another command.  Whenever I run the script, it sets all values in the column to the $owner.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but it is not working properly.

```
`Connect-MicrosoftTeams

#get list of teams
$TeamsFile = Get-Team | Select DisplayName, GroupID, Description | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Scripts\Microsoft_Teams_List.csv" -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation

#read row in CSV, add owner to new column.
ForEach ($Team in $TeamsFile) {
$Owner = Get-TeamUser -GroupId $Team.GroupID -Role Owner | Select Name

Write-Host $Team.GroupID " Owner: " $Owner.name

$TeamsFile = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Scripts\Microsoft_Teams_List.csv"
$TeamsFile | Select-Object -Property *, @{label = 'Team Owner'; expression = {$Owner.name}} 
}

$TeamsFile | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Scripts\Microsoft_Teams_List.csv" -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
```

`

Sample of existint CSV
[image]

Comment: could you show a part of csv file..it will be easier to trap the error, if we could replay the sample...And display the result waited

Comment: I uploaded the image in the main question.

Comment: If you want the first `$TeamsFile` to contain anything, you should use `Get-Team | Select DisplayName, GroupID, Description -OutVariable TeamsFile | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Scripts\Microsoft_Teams_List.csv" -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 2):

If you only need a merged output of two commands, you may make use of [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1):

```
Get-Team |
    Select DisplayName,GroupID,Description,
        @{n='Team Owner';e={(Get-TeamUser -GroupId $_.GroupID -Role Owner).Name}}
```

If you already have a CSV file of Team data and need just the owner, you may update your CSV row objects with a new property using a calculated property also:

```
(Import-CSV -LiteralPath 'C:\Scripts\Microsoft_Teams_List.csv' |
    Select *,@{n='Team Owner';e={(Get-TeamUser -GroupId $_.GroupID -Role Owner).Name}}) |
        Export-Csv -LiteralPath 'C:\Scripts\Microsoft_Teams_List.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

In your attempt, the following code does not yield the results you think:

```
$TeamsFile = Get-Team | Select DisplayName, GroupID, Description | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Scripts\Microsoft_Teams_List.csv" -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
```

`$TeamsFile` won't contain any output because all output was sent down the pipeline to `Export-Csv`. If you want to capture output before it is sent to `Export-Csv`, you can use the common parameter `-OutVariable`.

```
Get-Team | Select DisplayName, GroupID, Description -OutVariable TeamsFile |
    Export-CSV -Path "C:\Scripts\Microsoft_Teams_List.csv" -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
$TeamsFile # now contains your Teams
```

Comment: This worked!  Can the same login be applied for a 3rd command?  So if you want to find out which 'office' the team is used in, could you add this?  I don't think so as it is not working:

Get-Team |
    Select DisplayName,GroupID,Description, 
        @{n='Team Owner';e={(Get-TeamUser -GroupId $_.GroupID -Role Owner).user}}
             @{n='Office';e={(get-mailbox -identity $_.user).office}} |
                Export-CSV -Path "C:\Scripts\Microsoft_Teams_List.csv" -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation

Comment: You need a comma between the calculated property hash tables, but, yes, the same can be applied for a second property. There could be a point where running many commands for each input object will start to become slower than doing larger queries and filtering them down.

Answer (score 0):

If headers are the same, then you can keep source csv files in a directory and use this command to generate a combined csv.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Import-Csv | Export-Csv .\combinedreport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```